# How to set different expiration time for each session in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.6

I need to have several sessions in my Laravel project, and I need that each session has a specific lifetime.

But in Laravel documentation, I just find how to set a general lifetime for all session (in config/session) not for each one.

Comment: What would the "additional sessions" depend on? Other auth gaurds? etc? more info is needed

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yo can assume that I don't want to use default Laravel auth and I want to develop myself, so when a user login in a system he logged out after 20 min and when he logs in and check (remember me checkbox) he logged out after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `SessionManager`'s [`extend`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#registering-the-driver) function to modify the driver. For example if you were storing sessions in the database you could put the following in the `boot` method of a service provider (you'll probably want to move the logic but this should get you started)

```
\Session::extend('database_custom', function() {
    $table = config('session.table');

    $lifetime = request('remember') ? 60*24*2 : 20; //minutes

    $connection = config('session.connection');

    return new Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler(
        app('db')->connection($connection), $table, $lifetime , app()
    );
});
```

And in your `.env` you'd set the driver like `SESSION_DRIVER=database_custom`. Check `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager` for more examples.